# Why do I get a segmentation fault for this?

Tags: c++

I just want to create a simple C++ struct that has an int index and an int grayValue .The function is given the vector with the gray values. When I try to compile it I get a segmentation fault, does anyone know why? (didn't sort the vector) Thank you.

```
vector<gray> createStruct( vector<int> grayValues)
{
   vector <gray> grayStruct;
     for (int i = 0; i<grayValues.size();i++)
      {
         grayStruct[i].originalIndex= i;
         grayStruct[i].grayValue= grayValues[i];
     }

     return grayStruct;
}



int main() {

  vector <int> grayVals={411,21,78,23};
  vector <gray> grayStruct=createStruct(grayVals);
//  sort(grayStruct);

  for (int i = 0; i < grayStruct.size(); i++)
      {cout << grayStruct[i].originalIndex<<' '<<grayStruct[i].grayValue;
      cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: oh and this is the struct , sorry:  struct gray
{
    int originalIndex;
    int grayValue;

};

Comment: You never resize `grayStruct`, hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. what do you mean resize it?

Comment: It's created with size 0 and you don't perform any operation that will change its size (see the answer by @MikeCAT ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using elements of `grayStruct`, which actually doesn't exist, in the function `createStruct`.

You have to create elements before use or use `push_back()` to create elements.

Create elements via the constructor:

```
vector<gray> createStruct( vector<int> grayValues)
{
   vector <gray> grayStruct(grayValues.size()); // add number of elements to create
     for (int i = 0; i<grayValues.size();i++)
      {
         grayStruct[i].originalIndex= i;
         grayStruct[i].grayValue= grayValues[i];
     }

     return grayStruct;
}
```

Create elements via `resize()`:

```
vector<gray> createStruct( vector<int> grayValues)
{
   vector <gray> grayStruct;
   grayStruct.resize(grayValues.size()); // create elements
     for (int i = 0; i<grayValues.size();i++)
      {
         grayStruct[i].originalIndex= i;
         grayStruct[i].grayValue= grayValues[i];
     }

     return grayStruct;
}
```

Add elements one-by-one via `push_back()`:

```
vector<gray> createStruct( vector<int> grayValues)
{
   vector <gray> grayStruct;
     for (int i = 0; i<grayValues.size();i++)
      {
         gray value;
         value.originalIndex= i;
         value.grayValue= grayValues[i];
         grayStruct.push_back(value); // add an element
     }

     return grayStruct;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah how didn't I notice that, thanks a lot